# Install Windows 10 on VMWare Fusion 8.5.3

Tags: windows, vmware

I have a MacBook Pro running MacOS 10.12.2. It has VMWare Fusion 8.5.3.
I have a Windows 10 **usb install thumb drive** for installing both 32bit and 64bit Windows.

How do I install 64 bit windows into a virtual machine?

I have tried to Google, but it keeps turning up instructions for how to install using an iso image.

I have looked at the USB drive and cannot find iso images.

I have tried:

1. File->New ...
2. Create a custom virtual machine
3. Drop disk image into the file selector window that pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up downloading the ISO from Microsoft and installing it from the ISO.  I try not to accept my own answers so if someone wants to post this as the definitive answer explaining why the USB drive is not suitable for installation I will delete this answer and accept yours.